# Laravel Cashier create subscription with additional invoice data linked to customer

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I need to add optional custom data to customers and invoice data within my Laravel 10 application running Cashier 14. This is how I create a new subscription, how do I pass additional data that can be attributed to the customer and then show additional information such as tax, company address, details on invoices automatically for users.

```php
Auth::user()->newSubscription('default', $plan->stripe_id)
            ->withCoupon($coupon)
            ->create($request->input('token'));
```